# Prove supremum has infinite integration

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n : \mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$ be functions such that:

$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n} and \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n(x)=1 $$

Set $F(x)=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} f_n (x)$.

Prove that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}F(x)=\infty$

Who can give me some suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to use Monotone Convergence theorem. It may help to write the $\sup$ in terms of the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and that one could argue that 
$$1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n(x)~dx=\int\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)~dx=0$$
if  $\int F(x)~dx<\infty$, using an appropriate convergence result.